# Right syntax to get auto-complete in IDE, thanks to phpDocumentor?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, symfony, phpdoc

I'm experiencing some problems in auto-complete feature of NetBeans. I'm using NetBeans for a Symfony2 PHP project and phpDocumentor mainly for auto-complete feature (not for generating documentation).

What's the right syntax between these (or it's basically the same)?

### Fully qualified class names:

```
class MyClass
{

    /**
     * @param \MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return string
     */
    public function myFunction(\MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\User $user) { }

}
```

### Class names:

```
use \MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\User;

class MyClass
{

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return string
     */
    public function myFunction(User $user) { }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they are both correct.

Zend Studio (Eclipse) won't generate auto-completions unless the target class is part of the current project's Build Path.  Maybe NetBeans has something similar?

Exactly what problems are you having?

### EDIT

FYI, you *do* need to use a FQCN for return values, even if the right namespace is already in use. For example, if `MyClass::myFunction()` returns a **User**, you'd want to do this

```
use \MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\User;

class MyClass
{

    /**
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return \MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function myFunction(User $user) { }

}
```

Comment: Sometimes i'm getting auto complete and sometimes it seems not working. And yes, it happens of course with return values. I'll go for fqcn as you said. Btw, why i'm forced to use fqcn in return values?

Comment: Because that's how the parser works, I suspect.  Just like is says in the documentation (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), "Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules."  Therefore, the context being returned to needs to know the FQCN since it won't know about the imported namespace(s) from the called context.